# How can I move two dword into one qword?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I found similiar anwser [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29159561/how-can-i-move-two-words-into-a-double-word-variable), but it works only for 32bit. How can I do it in NASM in 64bit processor?

Comment: Actually I can't because while doing something like that: mov eax, 1, it overrides whole rax in 64bit.

Comment: But while doing last thing -> mov ecx into eax, first 4 bytes in rax becomes 0

Comment: As I said, no they don't, because in 64bit when you pass something to eax, first 4 bytes becomes zero. It differs than 32bit.

Comment: Exactly, in that way 64bit works.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is X86, just put the low order dword first, high order dword second. I'm not sure about nasm, but for masm:

```
        .data
myqwrd  dd     089abcdefh, 001234567h         ;0123456789abcdef low first
; ...
        .code
        mov     eax, qword ptr myqwrd
;       or for immediate store
        mov     qword ptr myqwrd, 0fedcba9876543210h
;       or from ebx (low), ecx (high)
        mov     edx,ecx
        shl     rdx,32
        mov     eax,ebx
        or      rax,rdx
```

Comment: `mov     qword ptr myqwrd, 0fedcba9876543210h` is impossible.  You can only use 64-bit immediates with [`mov r64, imm64`, not `r/m64`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html).  IMO just simplify by showing an example that starts with inputs in ECX and EDX, and finishes with a result in a 64-bit register, without messing around with memory.  IDK if you want to mention needing to zero-extend function args with a 32-bit MOV in case they contain high garbage, but bringing memory into this is just a distraction.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two double-word **consecutive** variables (one after another), assign them values separatedly, then get both values as one quad-word. I tested next code in this [online compiler](http://rextester.com/l/nasm_online_compiler) :

```
section .data
    dw1  : dd 0   ;◄■■ FIRST DOUBLE-WORD.
    dw2  : dd 0   ;◄■■ SECOND DOUBLE-WORD.

section .text
    global _start
_start:

    mov dword [dw2], 12345678h   ;◄■■ ONE DOUBLE-WORD.
    mov dword [dw1], 90ABCDEFh   ;◄■■ ANOTHER DOUBLE-WORD.
    mov rax, [dw1]               ;◄■■ GET ONE QUAD-WORD (1234567890ABCDEFh).
```

Notice how the **second** double-word (`dw2`) gets the **higher** value, and the **first** double-word (`dw1`) gets the **lower** value. Also notice how the quad-word is **extracted from the first variable** but it reaches the second variable because of the size of `rax`.

Previous code doesn't display anything to know what is going on in `RAX`, so this is my original code: it moves the value from `RAX` into a string, then displays the string (garbage chars) :

```
section .data
    str1 : db  '12345678',10
    len  : equ $-str1
    dw1  : dd 0
    dw2  : dd 0

section .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, str1
    mov edx, len
    int 80h             ;◄■■ DISPLAY STRING = "12345678".

    mov rax, 01234567890ABCDEFh ;◄■■ MOVE ONE QUAD-WORD DIRECTLY.
    mov [str1], rax    
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, str1
    mov edx, len
    int 80h             ;◄■■ DISPLAY STRING = "�ͫ�xV4"

    mov dword [dw2], 12345678h ;◄■■ MOVE ONE DOUBLE-WORD.
    mov dword [dw1], 90ABCDEFh ;◄■■ MOVE ANOTHER DOUBLE-WORD.
    mov rax, [dw1]
    mov [str1], rax    
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, str1
    mov edx, len
    int 80h            ;◄■■ DISPLAY STRING = "�ͫ�xV4" AGAIN!!!

    mov eax,1
    mov ebx,0
    int 80h
```

**EDIT :** previous is the "int 80h" version, next is the "syscall version" (thanks @MichaelPetch for telling me what registers I had to use), also tested in the same [online compiler](http://rextester.com/l/nasm_online_compiler) :

```
section .data
    str1 : db  '12345678',10
    len  : equ $-str1
    dw1  : dd 0
    dw2  : dd 0

section .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, str1
    mov rdx, len
    syscall             ;◄■■ DISPLAY STRING = "12345678".

    mov rax, 01234567890ABCDEFh ;◄■■ MOVE ONE QUAD-WORD DIRECTLY.
    mov [str1], rax    
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, str1
    mov rdx, len
    syscall             ;◄■■ DISPLAY STRING = "�ͫ�xV4"

    mov dword [dw2], 12345678h ;◄■■ MOVE ONE DOUBLE-WORD.
    mov dword [dw1], 90ABCDEFh ;◄■■ MOVE ANOTHER DOUBLE-WORD.
    mov rax, [dw1]
    mov [str1], rax    
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, str1
    mov rdx, len
    syscall            ;◄■■ DISPLAY STRING = "�ͫ�xV4" AGAIN!!!

    mov rax,60
    mov rdi,0
    syscall
```

Comment: Don't use `int 80h` in 64-bit code.  It's still the 32-bit ABI, so it truncates any pointers to 32-bit.  This means you can't pass stack pointers, for example.

Comment: The 64-bit `syscall` ABI, of course.  The system call numbers are different from the 32-bit ABI, as well as the order of registers used for passing args.  [links in the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

Comment: `syscall` instruction doesn't have operands, and the `syscall` numbers take parameters in different registers.

Comment: I tried `syscall` in rextester and it worked for a simple `Hello World` : http://rextester.com/VDVUNV32415

Comment: @MichaelPetch, oh my! You are right. I tested my code but I was using the same registers (I feel so dumb).

Comment: I think this would be a better answer if you just removed the version that uses 32-bit `int 0x80` calls from 64-bit code.  That's just a bad example that nobody should follow.  Of course, IDK what making system calls has to do with combining two dwords...  Seems like it adds a lot of code that isn't relevant to the problem.

Comment: If anyone wants to watch the code in action, they should just single-step it in a debugger.  Debuggers for x86-64 work well, so there's no excuse for anyone not to be using one.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I decided to keep both codes, it's for people who, like me, didn't know that registers changed in 64 bits syscall, so they can see the difference :) Anyway the real answer was suppose to be the first small block of code, the other two big ones were attempts to watch `rax` content.